# what is the difference between raube berauben and ausrauben

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english

As I searched on internet I could not find what is the main difference between those 3 verbs **rauben** **berauben** **ausrauben**.

- **rauben:** I found that it can be used like:
  *Geld, Schmuck, Ruhe, Kind, Schlaf, Atem, Nerven rauben*
- **berauben:** Well what I could find it can be used also as the verb rob but when I asked my teacher about it she told me no it can't be used as rob. Please tell me how can you use this word in the right form?
- **ausrauben:** Well it's also rob so I'm really confused about those 3 verbal usages.

Comment: Did you try www.duden.de?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rauben** is the base verb, it means *to take away by force*. You may find the following sentence in a newspaper

> Der Angreifer raubte ihr die Handtasche.

*The attacker robbed her bag.*

Nowadays, it's often used as a metaphor:

> Der Typ raubt mir den letzten Nerv.

*That dude jangles my nerves.*

---

Use **berauben** if you want to focus on the action instead of the objects robbed:

> Er hatte vor, sie zu berauben.

*He planned to rob her.*

Again, it's often used as a metaphor.

> Ihr Tritt ins Gemächt beraubte ihn seiner Sinne.

*Her kick into his balls took his consciousness away.*

---

**Ausrauben** means robbing all the valueables someone carries:

> Der Täter hatte mehrere Personen ausgeraubt.

*The offender had looted several people.*

---

Please also note there is a fine line between *stehlen* and *rauben* in German law. *Rauben* is done by force (threatening someone suffices) and gets the offender an inevitable one year visit to the prison. Strictly unadviseable.

Comment: thanks, I won't ever think to do something like this haha now its clear to me

Comment: Too bad, this would have made for a brilliant headline: "The offender found asking about German vocabulary related to robbery hours before robbing two tourists from Munich" xD ... "The victims later confirmed that the attacker impressed them with his language skills."

Comment: I am not amused.

Comment: I also thought that "berauben" is much in the sense of "beraubt werden" (passive view of things), while "ausrauben" is the active view of things, and finally "rauben" is generic in between.